# When I set type to image for input tag in html, the .checked in JavaScript always returns false

Tags: javascript, html

I have encountered an issue with html and JavaScript. Here is the issue:
When I set the type to image for  and check if the image is clicked with the method “getElementById(“btn1”).clicked” in JavaScript, the log always return false even if I clicked on the image and will only log "clicked third"(the last statement).

Does anyone have ideas on what’s going on?

Here is the code snippet:

```js
function checkThirdQuestion() {
  //var popup = document.getElementById("popup1");
  if (document.getElementById('question3-selection1').checked) {
    console.log("clicked first");
  } else if (document.getElementById('question3-selection2').checked) {
    console.log("clicked second");
  } else {
    console.log("clicked third");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="question3">
  <p>3. What is the keyword to create a subclass from a superclass?</p>
  <h6 id="popup3"></h6>
  <input type="image" src="inherit.png" id="question3-selection1" value="inherit" name="question3" onclick="checkThirdQuestion()">

  <br>
  <input type="image" src="implements.png" id="question3-selection2" value="implements" name="question3" onclick="checkThirdQuestion()">

  <br>
  <input type="image" src="extends.png" id="question3-selection3" value="extends" name="question3" onclick="checkThirdQuestion()">

  <div class="resetBtn">
    <button type="button" class="reset" onClick="reset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share a code snippet

Comment: @Shuvo I have uploaded the snippet. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you think that an image has an attribute called checked?

Comment: `checked` the word here is self explanatory .... why does an image has a check property ?

Comment: @mplungjan I am using <input> tag with the type image, and it’s clickable. But just when I log the .check, it will always return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only radios and chekboxes has checked attributes.

This works better

```js
function checkThirdQuestion(but) {
    console.log("clicked "+ but.id);
}
```

```html
<div class="question3">
  <p>3. What is the keyword to create a subclass from a superclass?</p>
  <h6 id="popup3"></h6>
  <input type="image" src="inherit.png" id="question3-selection1" value="inherit" name="question3" onclick="checkThirdQuestion(this)">

  <br>
  <input type="image" src="implements.png" id="question3-selection2" value="implements" name="question3" onclick="checkThirdQuestion(this)">

  <br>
  <input type="image" src="extends.png" id="question3-selection3" value="extends" name="question3" onclick="checkThirdQuestion(this)">

  <div class="resetBtn">
    <button type="button" class="reset" onClick="reset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I suspect you have a function for each question?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("questionnaire").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id, e.target.value)
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="questionnaire">
  <div class="question1">
    <p>1. What is the keyword to create a subclass from a superclass?</p>
    <h6 id="popup1"></h6>
    <input type="image" src="inherit.png" id="question1-selection1" value="inherit">
    <br>
    <input type="image" src="implements.png" id="question1-selection2" value="implements">

    <br>
    <input type="image" src="extends.png" id="question1-selection3" value="extends">

    <div class="resetBtn">
      <button type="button" class="reset" onClick="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="question2">
    <p>2. What is the keyword to create a subclass from a superclass?</p>
    <h6 id="popup2"></h6>
    <input type="image" src="inherit.png" id="question2-selection1" value="inherit">
    <br>
    <input type="image" src="implements.png" id="question2-selection2" value="implements">

    <br>
    <input type="image" src="extends.png" id="question2-selection3" value="extends">

    <div class="resetBtn">
      <button type="button" class="reset" onClick="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried the code and the console returned this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null".

Comment: Hi, I’ve resolved the issue by putting the script code at the end of the </body> Tag. Thank you.

Comment: I updated the answer  - you can wrap in `window.addEventListener("load", function() { })` and put the script anywhere

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Now my page is running correctly. Thank you again.